# C# Templates and special constructors

Tags: c#, generics, oop, templates

I have a set of some classes which are all capable of being constructored with an argument being an instance of a particular interface.  Since they all can be constructed by this same object (and the process during which this construction happens is largely the same in all cases), I figured perhaps templating would work.  Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
public static void dostuff<T, U> (List<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        func(new U(item).SpecialMember);
    }
}
```

Of course, that won't compile since `U` is templated and thus lacks `SpecialMember` as well as the `T` constructor.

Basically, any given implementation of the inteface `T` has certain features.  `U` is an implementation of `T which has an additional feature that is needed *and* which can be constructed from an any instance of`U`.

Advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately while constraints will get you *some* of the way there, there's no way to specify that a type has a constructor which takes certain argument: the only constructor you can require is a parameterless one.

Personally I'd like to see that change using an idea of ["static interfaces"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) (only usable for type constraints) but for the moment the best you'll get is a type factory or reflection - or possibly a parameterless constructor *and* an "Init" method in the interface. None of these are nice options, frankly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(VS.80).aspx) to the generic parameters which will allow you to access SpecialMember for example:

```
public class SpecialObjFactory<T,U> where T : ISpecialMethod
where u : new()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.  Add a factory method to your T interface that returns U types.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use generics to create an object like this. You can constraint the generic types like so:

```
public static void dostuff<T, U> (List<T> items) where T : SomeClass where U : SomethingElse
{
}
```

But this will only let you access members of those classes/interfaces, not constructors.

To expand on Joel's answer, you should add a method to the T interface (in my example, SomeClass) that takes a T object and returns a new U object. Something like the following:

```
public class SomeClass    
{
    CreateInstanceOfSomethingElse() { return new SomethingElse(this); }
}

public static void dostuff<T, U> (List<T> items) where T : SomeClass, U : SomethingElse
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        func(item.CreateInstanceOfSomethingElse().SpecialMember);
    }

}
```

As another completely different approach, you could specify that the doStuff method takes a `Func<T, U>` as well, which is supposed to create a U from a T object.

```
public static void dostuff<T, U> (List<T> items, Func<T, U> createU)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        func(createU(item).SpecialMember);
    }

}
```

This gets messy if your object creation is anything more complex than a simple lamba like

`t => new U(t)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void dostuff<T, U> (List<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        U obj = ( U )System.Activator.CreateInstance( typeof( U ), item );
        func(obj.SpecialMember);
    }
}
```